# How can I manage session in Android login/logout?

Tags: android, session

i successfully developed one login form. But now I am not able to manage session...also i have read more session concepts.but i can't do it.please explain me in detail. This is my code. Please help how I can use Session part here.

This is my coding part:

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
 private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
 private final String URL = "http://111.223.128.10:8085/AndroidLogin/services/Login?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   loginAction();

   }
   });
   }

 private void loginAction(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
   }

   }
```

Comment: The web service you consuming, You have access to its code base? or you have to use it they way it is?

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224913/android-session-management

Comment: the above link is not helpful for me.please explain me how is add session coding part is my coding part.

Answer (score 13):

Clear activity stack when doing logout operation.

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then back button will stay at LoginActivity since the activity stack is cleared.
I guess it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

check this one..
it will help you to maintain sessions in Android

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6112799/1358004

[Android App Strategy for keeping track of a login session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7706449/1358004) (this link will display all aspects in-terms of maintaining sessions for login / logout.

I guess it will help you.

Comment: it is useful for keep username until logout..but after logout button means it is go to login activity.now i ll go back to my activity on my emulator means it is displayed the displayed username activity.but i wish to need if i ll go back means it is redirect to login activity..so here ll manage session concepts..so please explain managing session concepts after clicked logout button also.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear your session like as

```
  MySession session = MySession .getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                    session.clear();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

just call `finish()` once the `logout` button is clicked way to use:

in activity call ==>`finish();`

in fragment call ==> `context.finish()`;

hope that helps.